# Como faz para usar o console para mostrar os valores da posição X e Y do mouse?

Tags: javascript, funções

> HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="scripts/jogo/personagem.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jogo/cenario.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

> JavaScript

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight); 
}

function draw(){
  background(200)
  circle(mouseX,mouseY,200)
}
```

> Como faz para aparece no console.log a posição do "mouseX" e do "mouseY" da bolinha branca ?

Comment: É necessário utilizar o evento [*mousemove*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event)

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?

Você tentou colocar essas variáveis dentro do console direto?

Dentro da função `draw()` tente colocar:

```
console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
```

E veja se vai aparecer no console diretamente, caso não, é preciso encontrar uma função que faça a conversão dessas variáveis, "mouseX" e "mouseY", para algum tipo de dado a ser exibido dentro console.

Veja se resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de utilização.

Aqui você tem o elemento onde vai capturar o mouse.

`const el = document.querySelector('.canvas);`

Aqui o evento que captura a posição dentro do elemento.

```
el.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    console.log(`X: ${e.clientX} - Y: ${e.clientY}`)
})
```